# Transferring touch focus to another view

Tags: android, events, view, focus, touch

This question is a bit awkward. Is it possible to transfer the touch focus of one view to another? Basically, say that you have a view that picks up the first `ACTION_DOWN` touch event, and then immediately wants to transfer the focus for all touch events to another view to handle with it's `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`. I thought that doing the following would make it work, but it didn't:

```
 @override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) {
      this.clearFocus();
      anotherView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      anotherView.requestFocus();
 }
```

Obviously, it seems to me that it just doesn't work that way. Could someone explain to me how I can go about doing something like this?

If it's still a bit difficult to understand my question, think about a regular button. When pressed, the button is highlighted (focused) and if you move your finger off the button but still keep your finger on the screen, the button becomes unfocused but still has control of the entire touch events (no other view can become focused even if you move over them). My question asks if it is possible to transfer this touch focus to another view to handle without having you to remove your finger off the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code might work

```
button1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
{           
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        if(hasFocus)                
            button2.requestFocus();             
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I worked around this was to have a single view "harness" whose sole purpose was to pass on the touch information to the other classes, who would then do the processing. Note that ViewA and B don't actually have to be views and extend the view class. Its not an ideal solution, but I don't think it's possible to solve this problem with the current Android framework (ICS/JB).

```
class ViewHarness extends View{

    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event){
    if(ViewA is selected)
        ViewA.onTouch(event);
    else
        ViewB.onTouch(event);
}
```