# nextFocusDown with inflated layouts

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a view which includes a few instances of a view that is inflated from an xml layout.

In the xml layout i defined the `android:nextFocusDown` property based on the ID assigned to the elements in that layout.

The problem now is when i click NEXT through the first instance of the layout everything works fine, but when i touch the first element of the next instance of the layout and click NEXT, it goes back to the top of the page (basically the corresponding field in the first instance)

My theory is that since they have the same id ( i used `android:id="@+id/..."` in the layout xml to define an id ) that it is just jumping to the first one.

Is there another way to define this, or maybe something i am missing? The layout is pretty complicated so I would prefer to be able to use the xml instead of creating all of the elements in code.

Thanks,
- Ken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic IDs, which can only be done in code. You can't go the xml route. Also, how are you handling click events, and do you have any EditTexts? How do you expect to hook to the correct Button/EditText if you're reusing IDs?

I think this approach might work for you: [Transferring touch focus to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729191/transferring-touch-focus-to-another-view)

You'll have to handle the focus changes yourself in code.

Comment: while i can get the correct views since i am inflating the layout then you can get the root view and call `view.findViewById(R.id.whatever)` and add click handlers from there

Comment: Ok yea im not sure if ill be able to use that, i think im going to have to abandon the xml, reluctantly it will make some pretty messy code, thanks for your help!